# How come I am only receiving one value from map function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to store all the values from result.createtimestamp into the time_stamp array, however it is only returning one result. not to sure why this is?

[image]

code:

```
let time_stamp = []

if(!createdIssueslength ){
    return null
} else {
   const lineChartData =  createdIssueslength.map(result => {

      time_stamp = result.create_timestamp
      console.log('from console', result.create_timestamp)
      
    })
}

console.log( 'time_stamp array',time_stamp);
```

Comment: `time_stamp = result.create_timestamp` it appears you are setting the array to a single time stamp and as it iterates in order it is the last timestamp. Maybe replace this line with `time_stamp.push(result.create_timestamp);`

Comment: The array::map needs to also return a value, the value you are mapping to, otherwise you'll have an array of undefined values. You are not adding the values into the `time_stamp` array, you are simply resetting the value each iteration. Don't use `map` if you aren't using the mapped array, use `forEach` to issue the side-effect of pushing into an external array.

Comment: If you aren't using the resulting values from `Array.prototype.map`, use `Array.prototype.forEach` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding your `time_stamp` for every iteration you are not adding the elements.
Do this instead:

```js
let time_stamp = []

if(!createdIssueslength ){
    return null
} else {
   time_stamp =  createdIssueslength.map(result => result.create_timestamp)
}

console.log( 'time_stamp array',time_stamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

On `createdIssueslength.map` function, you have assigned `result.create_timestamp` value to `time_stamp` variable.

So `time_stamp` value will be updated to the `create_timestamp` of each item.

To store all create_timestamp, it is needed to add that value to the array as follows.

```
const lineChartData =  createdIssueslength.map(result => {
  time_stamp.push(result.create_timestamp);  // This part should be updated.
  console.log('from console', result.create_timestamp)
})
```

Comment: Can you pls approve my answer if that helps? @stack

Comment: in 3 minutes I can certainly :)